# How to load Separate NIB Files for iPhone 4-inch and iPhone 3.5 inch?

Tags: ios, layout, ios6, nib

How can I load separate nib files for my iPhone app that checks whether the user has an iPhone 5/iPod Touch 4-inch screen versus a 3.5 inch screen?

Is this done in the init method?

**Details**
 - I am not using a storyboard for the entire app. At one point I do use a storyboard and call it up from one of the view controllers. (is there a way to differentiate for storyboards as well?)

- I am looking for a solution that initializes in each separate viewController... not something that I would put in the appdelegate that only runs once.
- Autolayout doesn't work in many situations situation for me. The designs are very graphical, and too much white space makes things look bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way!

- I make separate nib files, one for the 3.5" / iPhone non retina and one for the iPhone5
- I use a macro to check if the current phone is an iPhone 5 format or not. (1)
- For the normal initWithNibName:bundle: I write an exception so that they don't use the normal initializer. I name it @"Wrong initializer"
- I created a new designated initializer for the viewController naming it initForFormat:
- I use my macro and check against if the device is an iPhone 5 or not. if it is iphone5 then I init with the nib name ViewControllerIphone5

**Macro**
I got this macro from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13068238/1492368 from RayOfHope

```
 #define HEIGHT_IPHONE_5 568
#define IS_IPHONE   ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds ].size.height == HEIGHT_IPHONE_5 )
```

so In the new designated initializer initForLayout: I write

```
if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        self=[super initWithNibName:@"DetailViewControlleriPhone5" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self=[super initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
```

**Old Initializer**

I learned this from Big Nerd Ranch: 
to throw an exception when using the standard initializer

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Wrong initializer"
                                   reason:@"Use initForLayout:"
                                 userInfo:nil];
    return nil;
}
```

**Calling the View Controller from another ViewController/AppDelegate**
So when I call this DetailViewController from another view Controller or the appdelegate I write:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initForLayout];
```